# Mysql inq - querying multiple tables for results

Tags: mysql, count

I'm working on a issue tracking script and looking at the mysql statement I was able to get the counts of all the priority issues but got stuck with getting the count on the status.

How do I go about retrieving the status count using the mysql statement below?

```
tbl_status
index    status
 1         open
 2         closed
 3         pending

tbl_priority
index      priority
1           low
2           medium
3             high


tbl_incident
incident  priority   status
adfadf        1          2
adfsdf        2          2
adfadf        1          1
adfadf        3          2
adfasdf       1          3
```

I was able to group the priority as such (works):

```
Low 3
Hedium 1
high 1
```

Like the same results with status but its not working out. maybe asking too much from a single statement.

```
open 1
closed 3
high 1
```

```
try
{   $stmt = $dbcon1->query("SELECT COUNT(tbl_incident.status),
               tbl_priority.priority, count(tbl_incident.priority), tbl_status.status
          FROM tbl_incident

     LEFT JOIN tbl_priority 
            ON tbl_priority.index = tbl_incident.priority

     LEFT JOIN tbl_status 
            ON tbl_status.index = tbl_incident.status       


      GROUP BY tbl_priority.pry_priority ");    
        $priorityCount = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);       

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> maybe asking too much from a single statement.

Yes, try to separate statements for each question. It will be more efficient on my opinion.

For statuses:

```
select tbl_status.status, count(*)
from tbl_incident 
    inner join tbl_status on tbl_status.index = tbl_incident.status
group by tbl_status.status;
```

And for priority:

```
select tbl_priority.priority, count(*)
from tbl_incident 
    inner join tbl_priority on tbl_priority.index = tbl_incident.priority
group by tbl_priority.priority;
```